# Finding minimal polynomial given one root and two values

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, minimal-polynomials

I'm trying the following exercise:

> Find a minimum degree polynomial $ P(x) \in \Bbb C[x] : P(1)=2 \land P(i-1)=i \land P(-\pi i)=0  $.

The root lead to $ P(x) = (x + \pi i)Q(x) $

now using one of the two values I can calculate values of $ Q(x) $ i.e.:

$ P(1)=(1+\pi i)Q(1)=2 $

and then:

$Q(1)=\frac{2}{1+\pi i}$

or

$Q(1) = \frac{2(1-\pi i)}{1+\pi^2}$

I can do the same with the second value:

$ P(i-1) = (1-i+\pi i)Q(i-1) = i $

$ Q(i-1) = \frac{i}{(i-1+\pi i)}$

but now I'm stuck here... I cannot understand how to fully define $ P(x) $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first step
$$
P(x) = (x + \pi i)Q(x)
$$
is definitely right. We are seeking the minimal $P(x)$ such that $P(1) = 2$ and $P(i - 1) = i$. As you say, this means that we must have 
$$
Q(1) = \frac{2}{1 + \pi i}
$$
and 
$$
Q(i - 1) = \frac{i}{1 - i + \pi i}
$$
Thus, if we can find a polynomial $Q(x)$ that takes on the prescribed values at $1$ and $i - 1$, we have found a candidate polynomial $P(x)$. It is clear that $Q(x)$ cannot be constant. But, as you can check, $Q(x)$ can be taken to be a linear function (think point slope form). This will yield the minimal polynomial (up to multiplication by a constant) with the properties stated above.

Comment: My problem is just how to depict $ Q(x) $ starting from the computed constant values... I got what you mean but I lack of imagination (or maybe I just have to study a little more).

Comment: That's the right idea. Just make sure that the value of $Q(i- 1)$ is correct. I think I got a different answer than you.

Comment: yes... I got it I mixed up Q(.) values... the correct (I hope) slope expression should be:
$\frac{x-1}{i-2}=\frac{Q(x)-\frac{2}{1+\pi i}}{\frac{i}{1-i+\pi i}-\frac{2}{1+\pi i}}$
pretty ugly (again)...

Comment: Yeah... That's why I didn't write it out in my post. I wanted you to work through it yourself, and I couldn't bare to write up such an ugly expression.

Comment: I should ask, is it clear why the polynomial is minimal?

Comment: solving $Q(x)$ lead to a monstrous entity... besides this the only hint on the grade of the polinomial comes from you stating _It is clear that $Q(x)$ cannot be constant_ then it could be 1 or more... being 1 statisfy this... but of course I have to think to a better answer... :-)
Maybe I found one: since for different values of $x$ we have different values of $Q(x)$ then $Q(x)$ cannot be costant and thus should be of grade 1 or more... I won?

Comment: I think that's right. I would put it like this: We know that $P(x)$ must factorize as $(x + \pi i)Q(x)$. The least degree $Q(x)$ could have would be $0$, i.e. $Q(x)$ could be constant. But if $Q(x)$ were constant, then the conditions on $P(x)$ could clearly not be met. Thus, the least degree $Q(x)$ can have is $1$. Therefore, the least degree $P(x)$ can have is $1$ (the degree of $x + \pi i$) plus $1$ (the least possible degree of $Q(x)$), i.e. $2$. If we find a polynomial of degree $2$ which meets the conditions on $P(x)$ we have found *the* minimal $P(x)$ (up to multiplcation by a constant).

Comment: your argumentation sound better than mine... :-) thnx